# Sandcastle doesn't output everything from a F# assembly

Tags: f#, sandcastle

It only recognizes top-level non-function value declarations.
e.g. let a = 2
and doesn't produce documentation for functions or type definitions.

I've checked the xml documentation file and it has all the /// comments I put in the source, but none of them (except for the top level values) show up in the resulting html.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using C#-centric tools for F# documentation generation is usually pretty horrible. We started an alternative project a while ago, but it is not yet as mature as SandCastle: http://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/if-doc